# Increasing volume (power) of an companded A-law or U-law data without decoding

Tags: audio, compression

I have an 8Khz 8bit companded audio buffer with A-law or U-law. I want to increase the volume or power of this data so that it is more audible. I want to do this without decoding it to raw PCM data. 
In case of raw data i can just multiple the data with integer number and increase the audio power. But if i do the same thing with A-law audio then it just gets distorted (which i was expecting as it is companded).

Is it possible to manipulate the a-law/u-law data directly to increase its volume or the only way is to decode and the increase volume and encode it back.